# Any issues wiring high power switching power supplies to 3 phase power this way?

Tags: power, switch-mode-power-supply

I have to wire several high power loads to a 415 V 3 phase feed. In case it matters, this is in Singapore.

The loads have a switching power supply front end.  They are rated for 277 to 480 VAC and several thousand Watts.  I have live, neutral and protective earth wires for the input.

This is what the proposed installation would look like (minus circuit breakers to keep it simple).

Any issues with this at all?  I don't think so, but I thought I'd check.

Neutral is not used. Only L1, L2, L3 and PE, with the 3 switching power supplies presenting a balanced load.

[image]

Comment: As long as the power supplies don’t require a neutral, I don’t see any issues.

Comment: Note that, if each SMPS (n) has a 50A startup surge, the total surge will be 50A * n.  Also each SMPS must be an isolated type of course (otherwise their outputs cannot be connected in any way.)  Could also power them with all neutrals connected.

Comment: The outputs would never touch each other.  No problem.  What do you mean by "Could also power them with all neutrals connected"?  How do I get an effective 415 VAC if all the neutrals are connected together?

Comment: You wouldn't, and as your loads need 277V minimum the only way you can connect them is as shown in your diagram.

Comment: Right, that's why I was curious about the comment I understood to mean connecting all neutrals to the neutral line, which would not work.

Comment: If you have 240 V phase to neutral, you get 415 V phase to phase.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No problems with what is shown.

Add >400V MOVs L to N , or 640V L-L if not included. 10kA min. 40kA suggested

Delay Power Sequencing is suggested on power failure to minimize start surge unless designed with a soft-start.

Arc flash represents a potentially lethal hazard for those inexperienced in working with high voltages with high follow-on currents.

Some companies may wish to have electricians perform installations of HiV loads rather than IT personnel until such time as IT personnel can be trained on the proper safety precautions. !!

Comment: Interesting thought about the MOV's.  I would think that most quality SMPS's have built in protection matching their ratings.  I'll check with the manufacturer to verify.

Comment: MOV's are field serviceable due to limited discharge uses. Line filters can reduce the need .